# Fazer um select com elemento <ul>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu to querendo fazer um select sem usar a tag `select`, então eu to usando as tags `ul` e `li`.

Eu peguei os dados da tabela no banco usando PHP e fiz um dropdown com `jquery`.

Quando eu clico no botão **selecione uma opção**, ele me mostra as opções, mas quando eu tento selecionar uma opção, nada acontece, como eu faço para conseguir selecionar uma opção desse menu?

HTML e PHP:

```
<div class="dropdown-collapse actions search_category">
<?php if ( osc_count_categories() > 1) { ?>
    <?php osc_goto_first_category(); ?>
    <button class="search-button-index">
        <span> <?php _e('Select a category', OSCLASSWIZARDS_THEME_FOLDER); ?> </span>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <ul>
        <?php
            $i = 0;
            $code = osc_category_code();
         ?>
        <?php while ( osc_has_categories() ) { ?>
            <li><a id="<?php echo $code; ?>"><?php echo osc_category_name(); ?></a></li>
            <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".search_category button").click(function(){
    return $(".search_category ul").slideToggle(400),!1})
```

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML renderizado ou fazer um exemplo para podermos testar? Assim a pergunta fica mais fácil de responder com o que precisas.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite.
Tenta esse código javascript aqui.

```
$(".search_category li a").click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```